# Having trouble making div's side by side, and adding a title below the div

Tags: html, css

Whenever I try to make a few divs to make a navigation panel at the top of my page it ends up looking like this
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gafio.png)
But I would like those div's side by side, along with that I am unable to put text
I got it side by side at one part but the text would be on the same line as the div and it would push the div's to the left and using 
 wouldn't work
Heres the HTML:

```css
#topDivs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.myDiv {
  border: 2px outset black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.fill-div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#sec1 {
  background-color: darkred;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color: rgb(112, 172, 76);
}

#sec3 {
  background-color: rgb(252, 209, 42);
}

#sec4 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#mainText {
  border: 2px outset black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">

  <!--
    BOXES AT THE TOP
  -->
  <div id="topDivs">
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec1">
      <a href="index.html" class="fill-div">
        <p>
          <strong>Index</strong>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec2">
      <a href="interests.html" class="fill-div">
        <p>
          <strong>Interests</strong>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec3">
      <a href="education.html" class="fill-div">
        <p>
          <strong>Education</strong>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec4">
      <a href="contactme.html" class="fill-div" <style "text-decoration:none;" "color: white;">
        <p>
          <strong>Contact me</strong>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script>
```

All help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you share a picture of an example for the final result that you want please, but for what I had undertand just by changing the #topDivs display to flex it will work, if not, please share de pictur :D

Comment: nvm you alredy got the answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i would like those div's side by side

Is this what you mean?

[image: fixed]

Change this:

```css
#topDivs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

To this:

```css
#topDivs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
}
```

Just add `display: flex;`.

Comment: thank you so much, and the title text works with it aswell

Comment: You probably want to drop off the display: table and clear:both properties.

Answer (score 0):

Display flex works really well with this and it automatically lines up the child elements side by side.

I've also removed your `p` tags and `strong` tags and used CSS to style the text instead. All changes annoted in your code below. Hope this helps.

```css
#topDivs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  /* changed display:table to display:flex */
  display: flex;
}

.myDiv {
  border: 2px outset black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  /* not needed as it's a block level element anyway 
  display: block; */
}

.fill-div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* added these so you don't need the <strong> or <p> tags and places the text correctly and will work at various div heights*/
  font-weight:bold;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}

#sec1 {
  background-color: darkred;
}

#sec2 {
  background-color: rgb(112, 172, 76);
}

#sec3 {
  background-color: rgb(252, 209, 42);
}

#sec4 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#mainText {
  border: 2px outset black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  /* changed this from white to 'inherit' so if you change the container div text colour, the link colour follows it */
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">

  <!--
    BOXES AT THE TOP
  -->
  <div id="topDivs">
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec1">
      <a href="index.html" class="fill-div">Index</a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec2">
      <a href="interests.html" class="fill-div">Interests</a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec3">
      <a href="education.html" class="fill-div">Education</a>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="sec4">
      <a href="contactme.html" class="fill-div">Contact me</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script>
```